# Can I use a ThunderBorg is a dual motor controller on an Arduino UNO R3

Tags: motor, arduino-motor-shield

I am new to Arduino and Electronics and am thinking of making a 6 wheel drive all terrain platform similar to the MonsterBorg pi, but I want to use an Arduino instead of a Raspberry pi  to control the motors. The motors I intend to use need to be powerfull.
Any advice on what would be shield or motor controllers I should use would be a great help.

Comment: First select the motors and the batteries. Find the stall current of the motors. Then find a motor driver (or motor controller) that can handle the voltage and the stall current. The motor driver can be more expensive than the motors. Pololu has many motor drivers. A common mistake is that someone buys big motors and a tiny motor driver, for example motors with 60A stall current and a motor driver of 0.6A.

Comment: Hello Jot, Many thanks for this it has been very useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Hello,
You have many possibility for drive one or more motor.

- Transistor(1 motor)
- [L293D](https://www.engineersgarage.com/sites/default/files/L293D_1.jpg)(2 motor backward and forward or 4 motor just forward)
- [L298D](http://www.fixmasterelectronics.com.ph/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/L298-2-Channel-Motor-Driver.png) (like L293D but he support more Amp and Vol
- [L293D Adafruit shield](https://playground.arduino.cc/uploads/Main/adafruit-motorshield2.jpg)(4 motor)
- ...

Here is an example for

[L293D](https://www.engineersgarage.com/sites/default/files/L293D_1.jpg):

enable PWM(0-255), inputs digital(0-1).
Motor1 : Input1, Input2, Enable1,2

Motor2 : Input3, Input4, Enable3,4

```
void motor1RotationDirection(int input1arg, int input2arg){
    digitaleWrite(input1, input1arg);//  LOW  |  HIGH
    digitaleWrite(input2, input2arg);//  HIGH |  LOW
                                     //Forward|Backward
}

void motor1speedRotation(int speed){
    analogWrite(enableMotor1, speed);
}    //for motor2 is the same.
```

Comment: I have already use l293D for project.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply and the resource list. I think these will be of a great help.